# Structuring graphical desktop application

Tags: qt, javafx

Most examples of Qt, JavaFX or any other gui framework show what you can do with the various widgets, and eventually you'll see a drag-and-drop or drawing example, where you can move shapes around, or draw something on a canvas.

For something more complicated, where the position of the shapes *mean* something, like a proper drawing tool where dimensions are respected, coordinates have units like 'mm' or 'inches', or may exist in an alternate coordinate system, relationships and constraints have to be maintained, where there are things like references to other shapes, a history, etc., etc., it seems like the application should have its own internal model of things, something more suited to the application than just the scene graph required by the framework.  Maybe the application wishes to store the shapes in a database rather than a scene graph, or for whatever reason a hierarchical graph is not the proper model for the application.

I'm guessing this is MVC, MVVC, etc., which is usually done for text and database stuff, but I've not seen any example where the internal data are shapes that happen to be exactly representable by the framework.

So the question is how to implement this?

Should each movement of the GUI elements call back to something that manages an application's internal representation of those objects?  And should each change to the internal state, from say a layout algorithm, therefore cause an entire `update()` or `redraw()` cycle?

It seems wasteful to have two representations of things -- the application's proper model, and the framework's, but it seems more awkward to manage the application logic at the framework's level.

---

Edit from comment asking for example

I've been trying to implement a schematic capture tool in Clojure in my very rare "spare time".  User draws a box, but the `javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle` is actually represented as a `(defstruct Rectangle[])`.  When I write/read to disk, I don't want to write the actual `javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle` in-memory binary object.  I want to write an edn format such as `#Rectangle{posX #mm(10) posY #mm(13.2) width #mm(5) height #mm(6) #Color{0xaabbcc80} #StrokeWidth #mm(10)}` where `#mm` is my own struct representing a distance type (which can be converted to meters, inches, etc.), and `#Color` is again my own defstruct mapping to `javafx.scene.paint.Color`.  I'd like this data structure to be "the model" in application memory, so when I read/write, I just do a `(read-string...)` or `(pprint ...)`, and Clojure serializes/deserializes using `*print-dup* true`, `pprint`, and custom reader maps.  I have this part working.

However I'd like to bind the javafx `Rectangle`'s various properties to fields in my own internal data structure, so when the user moves stuff around, the application's representation also updates, using the correct units.  Obviously there is a mapping function which takes pixels to millimeters, inches, whatever, and back again.  This mapping concept would apply not only to physical distance, but to any other Javafx graphical property such as color, line width, font, etc.

Later on, when I get to the algorithms for automated layout, knowing where the pin locations are, etc., I want the algorithms to work on the in-memory application model, not the `javafx...Rectangle` and such.  Because the values are bound bidirectionally, the graphics will update as the algorithm runs.  Whether that's actually a good idea is TBD.

So this is a separation of model from view, done a million times.

I guess I'm just trying to get over having to represent stuff twice -- once in my application model, and once in the framework's model.  I think I've convinced myself this is the proper route.

Comment: I'm not sure this is specific enough to be on topic here, but in a summary, yes - if your shapes "mean" something more than just graphical things being rendered on a screen, then you should almost certainly decouple your rendering layer from your application layer. Sometimes this is just from a code quality perspective, but usually it's from a functionality perspective too (you often want to do collision detection, motion calculations etc. on a sub-pixel level, so need a separate model that's more precise than what you're rendering to perform those calculations.)

Comment: The question is too broad, try to give some code example to have something to grasp on to.